# using javascript to validate form

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript well at all but I need to use it to validate inputs on forms i've made. I've looked at many examples and i really can't see why it won't work. When i click submit, nothing happens at all, it just goes to the next page, like there isnt even any javascript there. sorry if it's a completely obvious answer, i have no experience with javascript so i have no idea what i'm looking for. i'm writing all of the code on the same page. thanks for any help.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform(theform) {
var reason = "";

reason += validateName(theform.name);
reason += validateSurname(theform.surname);
reason += validateEmail(theform.email);
reason += validateHomephone(theform.homephone);
reason += validateMobilephone(theform.mobilephone);
reason += validateAddress(theform.address);
reason += validateTown(theform.town);
reason += validateCounty(theform.county);
reason += validatePostcode(theform.postcode);
reason += validateEmpty(theform.empty);


if (reason != "") {
alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
return false;
}

alert("All fields are filled correctly");
return true;
}




function validateEmpty(fld) {
var error = "";

if (fld.value.length == 0) {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "The required field has not been filled in.\n"
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;  
}




function validateName(fld) {
var error = "";
var illegalChars = ^[a-z\s]*$; // allow letters, numbers

if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "You didn't enter a name.\n";
} else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "The name contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}



function validatSurname(fld) {
var error = "";
var illegalChars = ^[a-z\s]*$; // allow letters, numbers

if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "You didn't enter a surname.\n";
} else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "The surname contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}



function validateEmail(fld) {
var error="";
var tfld = trim(fld.value);                        // value of field with whitespace   trimmed off
var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;

if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    error = "You didn't enter an email address.\n";
} else if (!emailFilter.test(tfld)) {              //test email for illegal characters
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    error = "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
} else if (fld.value.match(illegalChars)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    error = "The email address contains illegal characters.\n";
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}


function validateHomenumber(fld) {
var error = "";
var stripped = fld.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');    

if (fld.value == "") {
    error = "You didn't enter a phone number.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
    error = "The home phone number contains illegal characters.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else if (!(stripped.length == 11)) {
    error = "The home phone number is the wrong length.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}

function validateMobilenumber(fld) {
var error = "";
var stripped = fld.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');    


if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
    error = "The mobile phone number contains illegal characters.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else if (!(stripped.length == 11)) {
    error = "The mobile phone number is the wrong length.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}

function validateAddress(fld) {
var error = "";

if (fld.value == "") {
    error = "You didn't enter a home address.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';

    }else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
    return error;
}

function validateTown(fld) {
var error = "";

if (fld.value == "") {
    error = "You didn't enter a town or city.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';

    }else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
    return error;
}


function validateCounty(fld) {
var error = "";

if (fld.value == "") {
    error = "You didn't enter a county.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';

    }else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
    return error;
}

function validatePostcode(fld) {
var error = "";     
var illegalChars = ^[a-z\s]*$;
var regPostcode = /^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/;

if (fld.value == "") {
    error = "You didn't enter a post code.\n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
     } 
     else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "The post code contains illegal characters.\n";
    else if ((fld.value.length < 7) || (fld.value.length > 8)) {
    error = "The post code is the wrong length. \n";
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
} else if (regpostcode.test(fld.value)) {
fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
error = "The post code isn't the correct format.\n";
}
} else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
}
return error;
}


function trim(s)
{
return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}
```

and the html

```
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<table class="formy" border="o" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#F4EC53"  align="center">
<th colspan="2" align="center">Booking Private Hire</th>
<form name="firstform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform(this)"  action="secondform.php">
<table summary="first form">
<tr>
<td><label for="Name">First name:</label></td>
<td><input name="Name" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td><label for="Surname">Surname:</label></td>
<td><input name="Surname" size="35" maxlength="25" type="password"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td><label for="Email">E-mail address:</label></td>
<td><input name="Email" size="35" maxlength="30" type="text"></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td><label for="Homephone">Home phone number:</label></td>
<td><input name="Homephone" size="35" maxlength="25" type="text"></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="Mobilephone">Mobile phone number:</label></td>
<td><input name="Mobilephone" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="Address">Home address:</label></td>
<td><input name="Address" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="Town">Town/city:</label></td>
<td><input name="Town" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="County">County:</label></td>
<td><input name="County" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="Postcode">Post code:</label></td>
<td><input name="Postcode" size="35" maxlength="50" type="text"></td>
</tr> 

<td> </td>
<td><input name="Submit" value="Send" type="submit" ></td>
<td> </td>

</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: nothing i can see, literally just goes to the next page and validates nothing

Comment: You can use jQuery validate...

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation


Greetings.

Comment: if error thrown in the validation form will submit often faster than error will show in console unless it is ajax submittal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The thing that finally got it working for me is this:
The field names you are referencing do not match the actual names of the fields.

```
reason += validateName(theform.name);
```

changed to

```
reason += validateName(theform.Name);
```

Also, there appear to be errors in your javascript code:

These lines do not parse:

```
var illegalChars = ^ [a - z\s] * $; // allow letters, numbers
```

validatePostcode() has a structural problem. This "else if" doesn't have a closing bracket before it.

```
else if ((fld.value.length < 7) || (fld.value.length > 8)) {
```

You may have been going for:

```
    if (fld.value == "") {
        error = "You didn't enter a post code.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
        error = "The post code contains illegal characters.\n";
    } else if ((fld.value.length < 7) || (fld.value.length > 8)) {
        error = "The post code is the wrong length. \n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (regpostcode.test(fld.value)) {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
        error = "The post code isn't the correct format.\n";
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be assigning anything to the variable 'theform'.

I'd guess a JS error is occurring, rendering the validation useless, so the form just gets submitted.

Comment: oh it used to be;
function validateform(theform) {;
and onsubmit="return validateform(this)"
but i saw on another example there was nothing in the () so i have no idea what im doing

Comment: Change to onsubmit="return validateform(this) and change your function definition to function validateform(theform) {

Comment: ok, i've changed this but still goes straight to next page with no validation

Answer (score 0):

According to your code & assuming you are familiar with jQuery do this altho there might be easier ways...

1) pass 'this' in your function

```
<form name="firstform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform(this)"  action="secondform.php">
```

2) validate function

```
function validateform(myForm)
{
  $(myForm).find('input').each(function(){
     var val_trim = $.trim($(this).val());
     var input_name = $(this).attr('name');
     if(val_trim.length == 0)
     {
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
        if(input_name == 'Email')
        {
           validateEmail(val_trim); 
        }
        else if(input_name == 'Country')
        {
           ...
        } 
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: hmm, im not familiar with jquery at all unfortunately, but i might have to give it a go, thanks!

Comment: Also keep in mind that it would be better to validate your input serverside instead of using javascript. Probably by using ajax so that you wont bother the user with silly redirects.